# No stacktrace with ` Internal Server Error`

Tags: django

I am in the process of developing a site. We have recently set up a public facing alpha installation. I am on the ADMINS list, DEBUG is False, and I am getting a few dozen emails about ERRORs.

This is because I have the default Django ERROR email handler which emails admins whenever an ERROR is logged. This is desirable and I want to leave this as such.

The problem is that instead of a stacktrace, I get `None`.

Below the `None` and where normally the stack trace would be, I get the detailed printout of the `WSGIRequest`.

I have checked locally and if I turn DEBUG = False and introduce some error and access the page which errors out, I get an email with a stack trace.

My log on my public-facing alpha install contains entries such as

```
ERROR 2013-05-19 00:44:54,524 base 26322 68378704 Internal Server Error: /
None
ERROR 2013-05-19 00:45:12,377 base 26321 60291344 Internal Server Error: /
None
ERROR 2013-05-19 00:59:26,014 base 26322 68378704 Internal Server Error: /
None
```

which seem to correspond to the emails.

The emails are not sent on all requests. A good portion of them seem to be a result of the Googlebot and Bing bot hitting the site.

Due to the lack of info in the error log, I am at a loss as to how to begin diagnosing and resolving this issue. Does anyone have any ideas as to why the error is not being logged and what the error could be?

Comment: Not sure this is relevant, but could you please tell more about the server architecture, what http server are you using, django version? (btw, you should have asked this question at DjangoCon :))

Comment: We are using nginx and django 1.5.1. I just got an email from a colleague that he is on top of it, so an answer should be coming shortly. Re: DjangoCon I am bummed that by the time I realized what was happening it was sold out.

Comment: I'm getting the same problem.

Ubuntu 12.04.2 LT on AWS
nginx/1.1.19
Django==1.5
MySQL-python==1.2.4
eventlet==0.12.1
greenlet==0.4.0
gunicorn==0.17.2